# grep hangs when executed using execvp function in my C program

Tags: c, shell, grep, pipe, io-redirection

I have written a bash like Linux shell in C.

(Link to my repository:https://github.com/oneiro-naut/wish 
 .The file `src/execute.c` has the execute_pipeline function in it)

I am having problem implementing builtin commands which produce some output. Builtins which do not produce any output like `cd` and `exit` work just fine. External commands run smoothly. Shell has support for pipe constructs and I/O redirection as well. The problem is when I try to run a internal command( which is just printing a message). When I redirect builtin command's output to grep command using a pipe the grep child process hangs which I think is happening because grep never encounters the end of stream(or EOF) while reading from the pipe.

NOTE:This does not happen when the pipeline has only external commands in it.(I have taken care that no (external)command finishes before the next command has not yet started therefore it does not hang there)

Here is a simplified version of my problem 
 `

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{

int pipe_fd[2] = {-1,-1};
int EXIT_STAT = 0;

pipe(pipe_fd);//creating pipe


char* argv[]={"grep","Radiohead",NULL};

int std_out_dup = dup(1);
dup2(pipe_fd[1],1); // redirecting stdout to parent pipe's read end
//close(pipe_fd[0]);//closing parent pipe's write end 

printf("Alice in Chains\n");
printf("Radiohead\n");
printf("Dinosaur Jr.\n");
printf("Pixies\n");
printf("Soundgarden\n");
printf("Porcupine Tree\n");
printf("Pain of Salvation\n");


pid_t pid = fork();
if(pid == 0)//child process
{
dup2(pipe_fd[0],0); //redirecting grep's stdin to parent pipe's write end
close(pipe_fd[1]);
execvp(argv[0],argv);//executing grep command
perror("\n");
exit(-1);
}


else if(pid > 0)//parent process
{

    int i;//closing pipes for parent
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        close(pipe_fd[i]);

    do{ // waiting for grep to exit
        waitpid(pid,&EXIT_STAT,WUNTRACED);
        //write(,"\x4",1);
    }while(!WIFEXITED(EXIT_STAT)&&!WIFSIGNALED(EXIT_STAT));
}
else ;//fork error

dup2(std_out_dup,1); // restore stdout fd for parent process



return 0;

}
```

`
Program hangs if I try to run it without printing anything.
But pressing ^D terminates the program producing the output:

`Alice in Chains
    Radiohead
    Dinosaur Jr.
    Pixies
    Soundgarden
    Porcupine Tree
    Pain of Salvation`

So it seems grep is not able reads indefinitely because it's not receiving any EOF signal.
Please point out my mistakes I am really confused.

EDIT: Now even pressing ^D does not terminate so I have to just ^C the program.

PROGRAM AFTER CORRECTION:

```
int main()
{

    int pipe_fd[2] = {-1,-1};
    int EXIT_STAT = 0;

    pipe(pipe_fd);//creating pipe


    char* argv[]={"grep","Radiohead",NULL};

    int std_out_dup = dup(1);
    //printf("%d \n",std_out_dup);
    dup2(pipe_fd[1],1); // redirecting stdout to parent pipe's read end
    //close(pipe_fd[0]);//closing parent pipe's write end 

    printf("Alice in Chains\n");
    printf("Radiohead\n");
    printf("Dinosaur Jr.\n");
    printf("Pixies\n");
    printf("Soundgarden\n");
    printf("Porcupine Tree\n");
    printf("Pain of Salvation\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)//child process
    {
    close(pipe_fd[1]);
    dup2(pipe_fd[0],0); //redirecting grep's stdin to parent pipe's write end
    dup2(std_out_dup,1); // restore stdout fd for parent process
    execvp(argv[0],argv);//executing grep command
    perror("\n");
    exit(-1);
    }


    else if(pid > 0)//parent process
    {

        int i;//closing pipes for parent

        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
           close(pipe_fd[i]);

        dup2(std_out_dup,1); // restore stdout fd for parent process

        do{ // waiting for grep to exit
            waitpid(pid,&EXIT_STAT,WUNTRACED);
        }while(!WIFEXITED(EXIT_STAT)&&!WIFSIGNALED(EXIT_STAT));
      }
          else ;//fork error



       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: By default, libc configures output that isn't going to a TTY to be heavily buffered, to favor throughput over latency. If stdin hangs open forever, and there isn't enough data being printed to force a flush, content can sit in that buffer indefinitely.

Comment: You are closing `pipe_fd[0]` before the `fork()` and then `dup2`ing it in the child after the `fork()`. The `dup2` call will fail because the old fd is not an open file descriptor.

Comment: ...anyhow, if EOF isn't seen, check that there aren't extra, unclosed copies of the write side of the FIFO held by other processes (f/e, from other instances of the same process spawned with a `fork()`).

Comment: @Ian Abbott Oh I didn't notice that thanks for pointing out. I will remove the close(fd) call and check. I haven't closed fd in my original file even then it kept hanging.

Comment: @Charles Duffy I will check it again thanks.

Comment: @IanAbbott I removed the close() call as you pointed out and because of that the ^D is not being detected now which is because now redirection is actually happening so grep is not taking input from stdin(its reading from pipe now)

Comment: ..but the problem remains...i closed the file descriptors wherever necessary...it is still hanging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should

**1.** restore the stdout in the child; otherwise the `grep` child process will write to the write end of the pipe which is its stdin.

Add a `dup2(std_out_dup,1)` just after the `if(pid == 0)//child process ... {`

**2.** add a `fflush(stdout)` after all those `.... printf("Pain of Salvation\n");` printfs; otherwise the stream will be flushed twice.

**3.** close all writing ends of the pipe in both the parent and the child; add either `dup2(std_out_dup,1)` or `close(1)` before the `wait` loop in the parent.

Comment: Thank you so much! didn't notice that before forking I had already redirected the stdout so in the child the stdout will be redirected by default (m I getting it right?@mosvy) can you tell me why would it be flushed twice? (I will try what you told)....Thank you so much again!

Comment: Terminating via `exit()` (not `_exit()`) or returning from `main` will cause the stdio _buffers_ to be flushed: when you call `printf`, the stuff isn't immediately flushed / written by default when not terminated by a newline and the stdout is not a terminal (in your case it's a pipe, not a terminal). It looked like you removed the `dup2(std_out_dup,1)` from the parent, so you should put it back, or `close(1)` in order to cause an EOF by closing the write end of the pipe.

Comment: I found that I wasn't closing the stdout_dup either after restoring stdout...which was causing it to hang in my shell code